# High pressure water comes out of sprinkler air blow out valve

Tags: plumbing

When I turn the irrigation valve on (my the main water valve), high pressure water comes out of the air blow out valve outside. Does this mean that there is leak in the pipe somewhere? The sprinklers work fine but the water out of the blow out valve never stops

Comment: You already found the leak.  The valve is weak/loose/ or broken.

Comment: Check to see if there is a ball valve I usually have a ball valve and then the male quick connector if the valve is open that is the leak.